# How to override SonataUserBundle templates

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I've installed SonataAdminBundle and SonataUserBundle and I'm trying to override some twig templates. I've done succesfully with all except with user_block.html.twig

This is my proyect ../app/Resources/ directory structure:

```
Resources/
├── ApplicationSonataUserBundle
│   └── views
│       ├── Admin
│       │   └── Core
│       │       └── user_block.html.twig   <--- it doesn't work
│       ├── layout.html.twig
│       ├── Profile
│       │   ├── action.html.twig
│       │   ├── edit_authentication.html.twig
│       │   ├── edit_profile.html.twig
│       │   └── show.html.twig
│       └── Security
│           └── login.html.twig
├── SonataAdminBundle
│   └── views
│       └── standard_layout.html.twig
└── TwigBundle
    └── views
        └── Exception
            └── error.html.twig
```

Also I've tried put it under SonataAdminBundle or SonataUserBundle directory but nothing, it didn't work for me.

How can I override user_block template?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer and mark it as accepted !

Comment: I couldn't answer until after eight hours because I haven't got reputation  enough ;)

Comment: @xabi82 what did you use to generate your ascii directory tree?

Comment: @codecowboy I used the 'tree' command on linux system. You can see an usage example following this link -> http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

The directory file structure shown before works fine. I've solved the problem just adding the necessary js and css on standard_layout.html.twig

```
{% block stylesheets %}
            ...

            <!-- custom stylesheets -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/css/mycssfile.css') }}" media="all">

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
            ...
            <!-- custom js -->
            <script src="{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/js/myscriptfile.css') }}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It's not a good practice override a template that belongs a third party bundle. You must use for example setTemplate. https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/templates.html#configuring-templates

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use the configuration, like this :

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout:                 
        user_block: '::Admin/user_block.html.twig'
```

And then put your template here : `app/Resources/views/Admin/user_block.html.twig`

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution :)